# Is MULTICURVE geometry in WKT valid according to the standard and open source community?

Tags: postgis, well-known-text, standards, well-known-binary

We are using Oracle function (SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY) for exporting geometry to WKT. Some geometries have MULTICURVE in WKT, like this one:

```
MULTICURVE (COMPOUNDCURVE (LINESTRING (3451418.006 5481808.951, 3451417.787 5481809.927, 3451409.995 5481806.744), LINESTRING (3451409.995 5481806.744, 3451418.006 5481808.951)), LINESTRING (3451418.006 5481808.951, 3451417.787 5481809.927, 3451409.995 5481806.744), LINESTRING (3451409.995 5481806.744, 3451418.006 5481808.951))
```

Then we store the geometries in PostgeSQL with PostGIS extension and geometry is valid from PostGIS point of view. But then we are using [WKB parser](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-wkb-java) in our app which does not support parsing for geometries with MULTICURVE instance. In the [implementation of simple features](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) we found on the page 24 that **MULTICURVE is only abstract class and instances shouldn't be created.**

But Oracle export geometry with MULTICURVE. PostGIS reads the MULTICURVE and QGIS also. We found some examples on the internet in the opensource libraries which are able to parse MULTICURVE geometries and are inluded in the examples of WKT.

Now we don't know if we have a bad standard or open source community use MULTICURVE despite of standard or if there is something else which we don't know.

Comment: There are different standards. You can read about how GDAL handles curve geometries from https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc49_curve_geometries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(MULTI)CURVES are *not* part of the *OGC Simple Feature Specification* for WKT/WKB representations (read the same document, chapters 7 & 8; p. 51 ff).
If I'm not mistaken, Oracle's spatial datatype references and representations follow the *ISO/IEC 13249-3* specification, which does define a multitude of complex geometry types (it's proprietary, so I can't give further details).
PostGIS has introduced many [non-OGC standard geometry types](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html) and e.g. supports MULTICURVES.

Comment: So it looks Oracle to_wktgeometry() function returns Extended WKT which Postgis use. And EWKT is not standardized by OGC. Is that right?

Comment: @Bulva I wasn't sure about Oracle, but yes, EWKT is non-standard format.

Comment: I do not believe that Oracle writes same extented WKT that PostGIS is using because PostGIS has it's own way for including also SRID in WKT http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromEWKT.html. But the geometry part should be similar.